# Passing value to a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have defined following function on `onClick` event of my anchor tag

```
onclick="display_details('New York')"
```

My `display_details` function looks like this:

```
function display_details(cityname)
 {        
  alert(+cityname);
  document.getElementById("menu").style.display='block';

}
```

However the value coming with alert is `"NaN"` instead of `"New York"`.

Comment: Because `New York` isn't a number. Your `+` before the `cityname` in your `alert` is trying to convert the string into a number. See [Unary Plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Comment: Change `alert(+cityname)` to `alert(cityname)`

Comment: @Pointy I suspect OP originally had something like `alert('Hello '+cityname)` but then thought they could get rid of the `'Hello '` without changing anything else.

Comment: @ajp15243 : yes offcourse mate however I can accept answer only after 10 mins

Comment: @user3541562 Bah I always forget about the time limit.

Comment: Also, while you're still learning JS, make sure to learn the right patterns. Strings in onclick attributes are bad practice. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener for the proper way to add event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because you are using a + sign, before the variable name, JavaScript is considering it as a Number. you may remove that '+' sign, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `alert` call is using the [unary `+` arithmetic operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29), which attempts to convert its operand (in this case `cityname`) to a number.  Since `cityname` is a string, the unary `+` cannot convert it and returns `NaN` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `+` here,you just need to use:

```
alert(cityname);
```

since `+` which is called as **[unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29)** in Javascript. This operator will try to convert your string `New York` to an integer and result in `NaN` (*Not a Number*)